# Upper and lower limits of Convex Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**Prove that the (A)sup of any collection of convex functions on (a,b) is convex on (a,b) and (B)the the pointwise limit of sequences of convex functions are convex. (C)What can you say about upper and lower limits of sequences of convex functions?**

Here's what I have for part (A):
Let $f_i$ be a collection of convex functions on (a,b) then by defn. $$f_i((1- \lambda )x+\lambda y )\leq (1- \lambda )f_i(x)+\lambda f_i(y)$$Now define $F=\sup f_i$ and suppose F is finite.

**Question: Can I just take the $\sup$ on both sides and be done with this part?**

Here's what I have for B:
Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of convex functions which converges pointwise to f. Then $$f_n((1- \lambda )x+\lambda y )\to f((1- \lambda )x+\lambda y )$$
$$(1- \lambda )f_n(x)+\lambda f_n(y)\to (1- \lambda )f(x)+\lambda f(y)$$

**Question: Does this imply $$f((1- \lambda )x+\lambda y )\leq (1- \lambda )f(x)+\lambda f(y)$$**
For part c, part A requires that the upper limit be convex. I think that the lower limit of the sequence need not be convex. Could be wrong though. If you could provide an example that would help me greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Sort of. First take the $\sup$ on the right hand side, **then** take
the $\sup$ of the left hand side.

Second question: You have $f_n((1-\lambda)x+ \lambda y) - (1-\lambda)f_n(x)- \lambda f_n(y) \le 0$. Now take limits, and the result follows since $(-\infty,0]$ is closed.

Example:
Let $f_n(x) = (-1)^n x$. Then $\liminf_n f_n(x) = -|x|$ which is not convex.